# Remapping C-x C-b to Open List of Buffers in Same Window

Tags: buffers, window

I use Emacs across different machines and operating systems. I noticed that when I press `C-x C-b` to get a list of all buffers, on some machines the list opens in the same window where the cursor is located and allows me to arrow through the list, using `ENTER` to select and open the buffer I desire.

Yet, on other machines this list opens in the other window (I usually have at least two open) and even after I switch to that window using `C-x o`, I am not able to arrow through the list, select and open.

How can I achieve the first type of behavior on the latter machines?

Comment: Do you have any customizations that you are using across these machines? One thing to check is exactly what command `C-x C-b` is bound to in each case, using `C-h k`.

Comment: Same behavior if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to see what causes the behavior.

Comment: See also `C-h v same-window-buffer-names RET` and `C-h v same-window-regexps RET` for determining which buffers should reuse the current window in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I highly recommend using `ibuffer` in place of the default `list-buffers` command.  This will provide not only the behaviour you're after, but also a tremendous amount of additional functionality in terms of filtering, grouping, and acting upon the listed buffers, should you wish to take advantage of that<sup>1</sup>.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)
```

Or, if you want to change *all* global `list-buffers` bindings to use `ibuffer`:

```
(global-set-key [remap list-buffers] 'ibuffer)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `ibuffer-mode`, or else type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> after <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ibuffer` (or after using its new keybinding).

Comment: Thanks. I installed it, and it appears really useful and handy thus far.