# What keys can I use to create/delete and select side windows?

Tags: key-bindings, window, help

I have a *shell* buffer that's a good candidate for a side window:
I also regularly use an org buffer, that's always good to have around.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/draft/manual/html_node/elisp/Side-Windows.html

I can't figure the keyboard shortcuts to:

- make a side window
- remove the side window
- focus in to the side window

Comment: Your question appears to be: what keys can you use to (1) show/create a side window, (2) hide/delete a side window, and (3) select a side window.

Comment: that's right mr d

Comment: Make a side window:  `(split-window (selected-window) nil 'right nil)`.   Remove the side window:  `(delete-window (window-in-direction 'right))`.  Focus in to the side window:  `(select-window (window-in-direction 'right))`.  See my previous answer regarding how to display a `*shell*` buffer in the desired window:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28924/2287 .  You may wish to set up your own keyboard shortcuts for commonly used functions.  For example, I like F11 to `delete-window` with no argument, and F12 to `delete-other-windows` with no argument.

Comment: @lawlist the elisp you mentioned creates regular splits. This question refers to the "original" side windows. In the emacs documentation it says "Note also that delete-other-windows cannot make a side window the only window on its frame ". Since your side window can be made the sole window, it looks to me like "(split-window (selected-window) nil 'right nil)" doesn't make a real side window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no "built in" shortcuts for this.
This answer uses lisp (which can be executed with Meta-:)
to create a side window. Focussing on the side window and pressing C-x 1 - 
emacs refuses to make the side window the sole window. So I guess
thats what we want.

Right now I'm doing

```
Meta-:
(display-buffer-in-side-window (get-buffer "*shell*") '((side . bottom)))
enter
```