# sub shell does not open on the same window I want

Tags: shell

I have a little issue, not too big but a little annoying.

Suppose I open 3 windows in my Emacs GNU like this:

[image]

Once I position myself in any window (the largest one, in this screenshot) and press/type <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `shell`, the sub shell opens in the **next** window, which is in this case the first one.

I wonder why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: The following link demonstrates how to make a shell buffer that does not display in any window by default, and then there are a variety of examples demonstrating how to display the shell buffer with built-in functions and there is also a custom function to display it wherever you want; e.g., above, below, left, right.  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28924/2287

Comment: (I wonder if this question might be a duplicate...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default emacs will display the shell buffer in a different window from the selected one. You can override this by using `display-buffer-alist` to specify different actions based on the buffer name. In this case, setting it to

```
(setq display-buffer-alist '((".*\\*shell\\*.*" display-buffer-same-window (nil))))
```

will get you the behaviour you want, although it's probably better to do

```
M-x customize-variable RET display-buffer-alist RET
```

There are many options available for how windows are chosen, read

```
C-h f display-buffer
```

for the gory details.